# php-fpm PDO drivers mysql not found in RHEL 7

Tags: php, mysql, rhel7

i got issue with PHP-FPM, php71w-mysql not installed on server and when i want install it i got this errors

```html
yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php71w-mysql
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php71w-mysql.x86_64 0:7.1.16-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18(libmysqlclient_18)(64bit) for package: php71w-mysql-7.1.16-1.w7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: php71w-mysql-7.1.16-1.w7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.56-2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: MariaDB-common-10.1.31-1.el7.centos.x86_64 conflicts mariadb-libs < 1:10.1.31-1.el7.centos
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: MariaDB-common conflicts with 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

also pdo-mysql driver not found in phpinfo() , what is the problem ?

[Check image here pls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmwE9.png)

Comment: Have you read the conflicts that are given? What have you tried to overcome them?

Comment: yehhh, i fix it :D
1 - 
yum --enablerepo=webtatic install php71w-mysqlnd
2- systemctl restart php-fpm
3- systemctl restart nginx